# JPA: replace referenced entities in List with detached objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have an entity called FileSet with a contained list of entities called File:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILESET")
public class FileSet {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "FILESET_MAPPING", //
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FILESET_ID"), //
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID"))
    private Collection<File> files = Lists.newArrayList();

    ...
}
```

And the File entity itself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE")
public class File {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FILE_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    private String fileNumber;

    ...
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is update the list of files in a file set. For this, I create new (detached) File objects with the same fileNumber and replace them in the list:

```
String fileNumberToReplace = "123";
File newFile = new File(fileNumberToReplace);

fileSet.getFiles().removeIf(file -> Objects.equals(fileNumberToReplace, file.getFileNumber()));
fileSet.getFiles().add(newFile);

entityManager.merge(fileSet);
```

I had thought that since CascadeType.ALL was active, JPA would automatically merge the detached elements in the list. However, I'm becoming the exception:

```
Multiple representations of the same entity are being merged
```

Then I tried merging the elements in the list individually and then the file set itself after that:

```
fileSet.getFiles().forEach(entityManager::merge);
entityManager.merge(fileSet);
```

And this didn't help. I'm fairly new to JPA so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could someone maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us the function where you call this first merge? I'd like to see your transaction management, maybe this merge of yours is redundant.

Comment: Also, even if `FileSet` is in a detached state before you call `em.merge()` and so `merge` is not redundant, I suspect `FileSet.files` is a set (and not a list) if it was obtained from the `entityManager` (since it is declared as a `Collection`). Are you sure `removeIf` actually works? Have you implemented `equals/hashCode` for the `File` entity?